# Entity Framework ASP.NET WEB API on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have deployed my WEB API EF6 in remote IIS server.
It is failed to access remote DB server `db.Database.Exists()` returns `false` . Whereas in my local PC it is working fine and able to connect the DB and  `db.Database.Exists()` returns `true`.

What changes should I do in the ConnectionString.
My connectionstring looks like this:

```
<add name="myconnstring" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.InformationSystem.csdl|res://*/Models.InformationSystem.ssdl|res://*/Models.InformationSystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server01;Initial Catalog=myDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abcd;Password=abcd;initial catalog=myDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: <add name="myconnstring" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.InformationSystem.csdl|res://*/Models.InformationSystem.ssdl|res://*/Models.InformationSystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server01;Initial Catalog=myDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abcd;Password=abcd;initial catalog=myDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

Comment: Try to telnet from your web server to your database server on port 1433 to ensure this is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is on a different box than your development box and that connection string works, then there is nothing wrong with the connection string. The issue would be in either authorization or actual connectivity from the IIS server to the DB server. Without knowing your network structure and/or the specific error message, more specifics can't be offered.